# How to iterate over nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array, foreach

Here's what I have:

```
$nav = array (
    "page 1" => array (
        "page 1.1" => array (
            "page 1.1.1"
            "page 1.1.2"
        ) ,
        "page 1.2"
    )
    "page 2" => array (
        "page 2.1"
    )
);
```

And here's what I want:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>page 1
            <ul>
                <li>page 1.1
                    <ul>
                        <li>page 1.1.1</li>
                        <li>page 1.1.2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>page 1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>page 2
            <ul>
                <li>page 2.1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

What I have so far:

```
foreach ($nav as $key => $val) {
    if (!is_numeric($key)) {
        $nav_entry = $key;
    } else {
        $nav_entry = $val;
    }
    echo "<li>" . $nav_entry . "</li>";
}
```

My problem here is that, I need to have that foreach loop if and whenever there's a child array. On top of that, I need to somehow fit in an `if` statement to add in the `<ul></ul>` tag...

I started seeing stars... too confusing.

Comment: Where does "home" fit into your output?

Comment: @RobertCathey I'm sorry! That was just confusion on my side from working on a real page. > > Removing it.

Comment: I almost have it. Just having a weird problem.

Comment: Got it. Will work completely recursively.

Comment: Ty to everyone! Tested, they all work. Just chose the one with shortest coding and easiest to read... @ @;;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that :)

```
function createMenu($nav){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($nav as $key => $row){
        if(!is_array($row)){
            echo "<li>".$row."</li>";
        }else{
            echo "<li>".$key;
                createMenu($row);
            echo "</li>";

        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

createMenu($nav);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [
    'home',
    'page 1' => [
        'page 1.1' => [
            'page 1.1.1',
            'page 1.1.2'
        ],
        'page 1.2'
    ],
    'page 2' => [
        'page 2.1'
    ]
];

function buildLists($array) {
    $result = '';
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(!is_int($key)) {
            $result .= '<li>' . $key;
        } else if(!is_array($value)) {
            $result .= '<li>' . $value;
        }
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result .= '<ul>';
            $result .= buildLists($value);
            $result .= '</ul>';
        } else {
            $result .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
       <?= buildLists($array); ?>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

output:

```
<li>home</li>
<li>page 1
    <ul>
        <li>page 1.1
            <ul>
                <li>page 1.1.1</li>
                <li>page 1.1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>page 1.2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>page 2
    <ul>
        <li>page 2.1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
$nav = array (
    "page 1" => array (
        "page 1.1" => array (
            "page 1.1.1",
            "page 1.1.2"
        ),
        "page 1.2"
    ),
    "page 2" => array (
        "page 2.1"
    )
);

function drawRecursive($list){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($list as $key=>$item){
        echo "<li>";
        if (is_array($item)){
            echo $key;
            drawRecursive($item);
        } else {
            echo $item;
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

echo "<nav>";
drawRecursive($nav);
echo "</nav>";
?>
```